# jetty 9 - HttpServletResponse.SC_CONTINUE not work

Tags: servlets, jetty

I use simple code

```
servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONTINUE);
servletResponse.flushBuffer();
```

In jetty 8.1 it works fine.
In jetty 9.0 I get 504 result.

Do you know where problem could be? Is it somewhere in newest jetty 9.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty handles sending 100 Continue responses automatically for you, so you should not have to do this.

For a 100 continue to be sent the client must send and expectation and the servlet must call request.getInputStream (or reader or a parameters method).